# Same PHP script gives different error with PHP 5.3.10 and PHP 5.3.6-13

Tags: php

I have a WordPress cache plugin, name wp-ffpc. I've received some error report running it on Amazon Linux, with PHP 5.3.10. I've tested it on an Ubuntu 11.10 machine, with the bundled 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3 version.

It turned out - after calling the script from mere command line - that the difference has to be related to the PHP binary itself.

Ubuntu 11.10, PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3

```
php wp-ffpc.php
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_option() in /home/webportfolio.hu/tmp/wp-ffpc.php on line 31
```

This is what expected from the code. Now running the exactly same, scp-d version on the Amazon linux machine:

```
[root@aws wp-ffpc]# php wp-ffpc.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in PATH/To//wp-ffpc.php on line 408
```

Has anybody encountered with a problem like this? Any idea what may cause the problem?
The [tested source code is right here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-ffpc/trunk/wp-ffpc.php).

### EDIT

**I expect the undifined function error message, that is the correct working, since this script is a WordPress plugin and unable to run in standalone mode from command line.**

**The problem is that on the other server the error message is entirely different and the script does not even gets to the point of running/beeing parsed.**

Please read before commenting or trying to answer.

Comment: You can't call it directly from the command line, it is expecting to be included from another file, in an environment where functions like `get_option` are already defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is, that in line 387 you are using short open tags:

```
<? endif; ?>
```

This might not work on every machine, since it needs to be activated [in the php config with short_open_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).
Therefore, on one machine, the endif is "ignored" and the php code looks like this:

```
<?php if ( $this->options['cache_type'] == 'memcache' ) : ?> [...] <?php }
```

which obviously produces the error message "syntax error, unexpected '}'".

#### Fix:

Just don't use the short open tags for now (they will always be enabled in PHP 5.4, though).

Comment: Just finished my own debugging. I came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Hm. Thanks, I'll give a try. Strange tought that most of the wordpress plugins uses them, and I have not heard problems on those ones yet.

Comment: You have to differ between the short_open_tags <? echo $a; ?> and the short output tags <?=$a?>. The latter ones always work, the former one is depending on the configuration flag.